# 2d array of type Space

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a 9x9 grid of Spaces with 1-10 int values. I'm using the java n-ide app, and am getting a successful compilation, but it's not printing any values.

```
class Space {
    int one = 1;
    int two = 2;
    ...
    int ten = 10;
}

class green {
    Space[][] board = new Space[9][9];

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            board[i][j] = new Space();
            System.out.println(board[i][j].one);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just refactor your `Space` class to just hold a primitive integer value:

```
class Space {
    private int value;
    private static final String MSG = "Space values must be between 1 and 10 inclusive";

    public Space() { }

    public Space(int value) {
        // prevent spaces from being created with illegal values
        if (value < 1 || value > 10) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MSG);
        }
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then, in your consuming class, use the `Space` class:

```
class Green {
    private Space[][] board = new Space[9][9];

    for (int i=0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            // maybe get a value from somewhere and use it below
            board[i][j] = new Space();
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding your exact question about values not printing, the bigger problem than above is that you don't have any logic for assigning values.